# Firebase HTTP endpoint servers

Tags: firebase

When you connect your domain `example.com` to Firebase, and export cloud functions, why are you only able to access the functions from `us-central1...cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld`? I would like to access from `example.com/helloWorld`.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since you are answering your own question, you need to put it in the Answers section. Do not just edit your question where no one will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the documentation on [directing Firebase Hosting requests to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function):

> ```
> // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
> "rewrites": [ {
>   "source": "/bigben", "function": "bigben"
> } ]
> ```